# Key Security - How to ensure that keys are secure?

Tags: java, security, secure-coding

Assuming that there is a Key Encryption Key that is in memory and not written to file or database...

```
byte[] kek = new byte[32];
secureRandom.nextBytes(kek);
byte[] kekHash = SHA512.hash(kek);
```

And assuming that the Key Encryption Keys are ephemeral, and the Data Encryption Keys may or may not be ephemeral.

How do you protect `kek`?

How do you ensure that `kek` is never written to virtual memory?

How do you ensure that the `kek` is not read by another application (for example CheatEngine)?

How do you ensure that the `kek` is generated by the application and the `kek` and `kekHash` are not manipulated by another application to make it use the key of an adversary?

I have heard of "software HSM". What techniques do they use that is so mindblowing that makes the keys that they store secure?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to truly secure your encryption key, you have to use an Hardware Security Module (HSM). These are physical devices which can store your keys securely. You can read more about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module).

In your current scenario you would be generating the encryption keys using the software (java in this case), and you would perform cipher operations (encryption/decryption) on the software as well. But when you use an HSM, you would actually be generating and storing your keys on the hardware, and you would perform the cipher operation on the hardware itself, but not the software. And there are many configuration you have to do for your software to talk to the hardware. So it not that easy to get into the HSM and see the keys. This is just a high level of how you would use an HSM. PKCS#11 API is generally used to interact with hardware. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_11).

These devices usually come in 3 major form factory: HSM (these are as big as servers), USB token, Smart Card. These devices can run from few hundred to thousand dollars.

So for those who want to try how the HSM works or if it is expensive to afford or just want to do some R&D for their project, you could use the SoftHSM. Which means, you would interact with the SoftHSM software as you would interact with the hardware as usual (using PKCS#11), but your keys are actually stored on the software. Since SoftHSM is not a physical device, it is a software you would install on your machine. The cipher operations are also done on the software. And in the future when you are ready to integrate with a physical HSM, you could just use your SoftHSM code. You could refer to the SoftHSM documentation [here](https://www.opendnssec.org/softhsm/).

So to truly store your keys securely, you could use an HSM. But when you use software, there is always an open end. Lets say even if you have a super master key that encrypts your encryption keys, you have to store the super master key somewhere. Usually stored in a Java KeyStore. And Java KeyStore is password protected, and you have to store it somewhere as well.

One way you could approach little higher security is to have your code obfuscated which performs these crucial operations. Even the obfuscation can break, but it is time taking and little harder.

Comment: Hello, I appreciate the answer you have given. I have experience with HSMs but am looking for a software solution at the moment, and perhaps some mindblowing way to protect the Key Encryption Key. Additionally, while I appreciate your obfuscation suggestion, I must say that it is pretty standard to use ProGuard with Java or some other commercially available obfuscator. More importantly, according to Kirchoff's principle, it's assumed that the adversary has perfect knowledge of the system except the value of the keys and security through obscurity/secrecy of the codes/system is unacceptable.